I need some guidance to build this widget
I am trying to build a widget that looks like this, and i need some guidance on how to build the lights.
so this widget works like a counter, once all the lights are on the counter gets incremented by one, and the lights are turned on by clicking the inner circle where the text is placed, and the text also changes with each light.
i think i will build the inner circle by using a card and container and give them a circular shape, and pass a text inside a center widget as a child, and track the light and text displayed using a normal get controller.
what i don't know how to create is the outer shape (lights) that should turn on/off depending on the turn.
i tried looking for an external library that works somewhat like this but came up with nothing, any guidance or help with building this or finding a similar will be much appreciated.

You can achieve this layout using the drawArc function of the Flutter CustomPaint widget's canvas.
